# how to put only session auth in laravel

Tags: laravel, firebase, laravel-authentication

**Web.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth:admin'], function(){
    Route::resource('dashboard', 'DashboardController');

    Route::group(['prefix'=>'users','namespace'=>'User','as'=>'u.'], function(){
        Route::resource('list',     'ListController');
        Route::resource('segments', 'SegmentController');
    });
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'sales','namespace'=>'Sales','as'=>'s.'], function(){
        Route::resource('credits',   'CreditController');
        Route::resource('packages',  'PackageController');
    });
});
```

**RedirectIfAuthenticated**

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard)
    {
        if(Session::has('admin_session')){
            return redirect('admin/dashboard');
        }
    // if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
    //     return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    // }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**AuthController**

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/firebaseKey.json');
    $firebase= (new Factory)->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)->create();
    $this->database = $firebase->getDatabase();

    $auth = $firebase->getAuth();
    // if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
       //      return redirect('admin/dashboard');
    // }
    try {
        if($user = $auth->verifyPassword($request->email,$request->password)){
            Session::put('admin_session',$user);
            return redirect('admin/dashboard');
        }
    } catch (\Kreait\Firebase\Exception\Auth\InvalidPassword $e) {
        echo 'wrong password'; die();
    } catch (\Kreait\Firebase\Auth\SignIn\FailedToSignIn $e) {
        echo 'invalid email'; die();
    }
}
```

How to put only session authentication on above-mentioned routes?
As I want to put **firebase** authentication so laravel's wouldn't work here,

So I just want to implement simple `isset(session('admin_session'))` functionality which will be common for all routes...

Anyone, please suggest me how to implement it... it keeps redirecting!

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question, but I guess you need a Middleware : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware

Comment: I want to implement only `session()` auth for routes I mentioned above as I should not put `if(isset(session())) return home page` to every Controller's constructor

Comment: @VincentDecaux Here, have a look on what I exactly expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change the middleware group to a new middleware name:

**Web.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'role'], function(){      //or the name you want to use
    Route::resource('dashboard', 'DashboardController');

    Route::group(['prefix'=>'users','namespace'=>'User','as'=>'u.'], function(){
        Route::resource('list',     'ListController');
        Route::resource('segments', 'SegmentController');
    });
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'sales','namespace'=>'Sales','as'=>'s.'], function(){
        Route::resource('credits',   'CreditController');
        Route::resource('packages',  'PackageController');
    });
});
```

2. Create a new middleware by `php artisan make:middleware Role` :

**Role.php** (Middleware)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Session;
use Closure;

class Role
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Session::has('admin_session')) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
}
```

3. Modify the RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware to this:

**RedirectIfAuthenticated.php**

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Session::has('admin_session')) {
            return redirect('admin/dashboard');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

4. Modify AuthController to this:

**AuthController.php**

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if ($auth = $this->firebase->getAuth()) {
        try {
            $user = $auth->verifyPassword($request->email, $request->password);
            Session::put('admin_session',$user);
            return redirect('admin/dashboard');
        }
        catch (\Kreait\Firebase\Exception\Auth\InvalidPassword $e) {
            return back();  // code for wrong password
        }
        catch (\Kreait\Firebase\Auth\SignIn\FailedToSignIn $e) {
            return back();  //code for user doesn't exists
        }
    }
    return back();  // something went wrong
}
```